# Lambda function is not triggered using Cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I have an event in AWS Serverless with the following YML :

```
service: change-status-to-insale
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
functions:
  changeWeeklyStarterStatus:
    # Two Minutes : 0 */2 * ? * *   
    handler: handler.changeWeeklyStarterStatus
    schedule: cron(0 */2 * ? * *)
    enabled: true
```

I've uploaded using the command

```
serverless deploy
```

I've tried to invoke it every 2 minutes using the formula :

```
0 */2 * ? * *
```

However the event is not triggered.

I've tested it using the **Test button** and it runs the function perfectly.

But it's still not triggered.

Why ? What am I missing ?

Comment: 0 */2 * ? * * (it's basically for At minute 0 past every 2nd hour.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used wrong configuration for cron expression. use ***/2 * * * ? *** for every 2 minute.

How to schedule from AWS Cloudwatch

[image]

Comment: Thanks , I've changed it to your formula and it's still not invoked.

Comment: Why don't you use the AWS Cloudwatch console service and schedule it from there using the Events. Just create a new rule, schedule it and set Target as your lambda . It's working for me.

Comment: I have edited my answer and attached the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: You're awesome ! So what's the deal with the YAML file ? it doesn't do the job ? useless ?

Comment: Thanks :) Not sure about that, may be for just local invocation as SAM Template it's required, will check and update.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the help.